# jQuery .show() not working until a refresh is made

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery function to display various things depending on whether a user was logged in or not.

The function is in the header which is included in every page (I tried it within the head of the page in question with the same result.

The id loggedIn is set to display:none and the the jquery should display it once logged in but it never does.

I've tested with both loggedIn and loggedOut but nether appear, however the head does update the links, albeit after a refresh and that's the other issue.
In the header, I have to refresh the page before the links change.

Thanks tons for any help.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loggedIn = <? php echo json_encode($general - > loggedIn()); ?> ;
    if (loggedIn == true) {
        $("#loggedIn").show();
    } else {
        $("#loggedOut").show();
    }
});            
</script>
```

Neither of the loggedIn or loggedOut elements display in the below code.

```
<p id="loggedOut">YOOOOHOOOOOOO</p>
  </div>

<?php

 $body = <<<EOT
        <div class="viewAndDownload" id="loggedIn">
            <a href="../download.php?filename=bla.pdf">Click to download the PDF/>
</div>
EOT;
```

This is the HTML from the header where the login box doesn't show until after a refresh:

```
<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id="loggedIn">
    Links Here
</nav>

<nav class = "memberHeaderArea" id ="loggedOut">
 Removed links etc to save space
<input type="submit" name="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login!"   onclick="validLogin(); return false;"/>
```

onclick calls an ajax function

```
function validLogin(){

//removed get username etc

var params = {username: username, password: password};
var url = "../loginProcessAjax.php";

$("#statusLogin").show();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      document.getElementById("statusLogin").innerHTML= '<img src="../images/loginLoading.gif" /> checking...' ;
    },

    success: function(data) {

        $("#statusLogin").hide();

        if(data.success == true){

            //$('#loggedIn').show();
            $('#loginContent').slideToggle();
            //$('#loggedOut').hide();

        }else{
           // alert("data.message... " + data.message);//undefined
            $("#error").show().html(data.message);
        }

    },
    error: function( error ) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
}
```

Thank you again, this has been bugging me for ages and I haven't found a way to solve it despite many attempts

EDIT: logged in function

```
public function loggedIn(){

return (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
}//end function
```

Comment: Is there any error in `console.log`?

Comment: @DKM - no, none at all.

Comment: You are checking if php output is true/false, but you are not printing out a bollean (json encode part). Is this intended? You can't pass a bollean from php to javascript like this

Comment: what do you get in variable loggedIn?

Comment: @Skarlinski - but...the links change after a refresh? Surely if it wasn't getting true, they wouldn't change at all?

Comment: instead of use `.show()` / `.hide`, use `addClass`/`removeClass` make a class `.hide { display: none; }`.

Comment: @PiyushArora - it returns true or false - I'll paste it in the question

Comment: Since your function is called only on dom ready , i don't know how you want it to work without refresh.

Comment: @nubinub - The 'plan' is to have a rolldown login box that allows a user to login and then updates the links automaticially while on the same page - are you suggesting I remove the doc.ready?

Comment: You have to use setInterval to keep calling this function.

Comment: @nubinub could you elaborate please, I'm a bit of a newbie

Comment: The thing is you are expecting your page to update whenether you log in, but since the function supposed to display hidden div is called only on page load, you won't be able to display those divs if you don't refresh the page. Using setInterval will keep calling this function based on the interval you specified.

Comment: @nubinub - He is using ajax to "refresh" the login area. But it is not clear when this ajax request is triggered.

Comment: @Skarlinski - The ajax is called on sumbit.  validLogin()

Comment: Are you sure the ajax is really called? you can use console to find out (if you are using chrome right click and console area and  choose log xmlhttprequests)
It should show you all ajax calls sent and their responses.

Comment: @Skarlinski  -yes, the ajax is being called, otherwise I wouldn't be able to log in at all :) all sorted now though, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function testLoggedIn(){
      var loggedIn = <? php echo json_encode($general - > loggedIn()); ?> ;
        if (loggedIn == true) {
          $("#loggedIn").show();
        } else {
          $("#loggedOut").show();
        }
    }

    setInterval(testLoggedIn(),1000);
});
```

Something like this should work.

**EDIT**
The main idea is you have to constantly check if the user is logged in or not and not only on document ready. To achieve that you can use `setInterval` which will keep executing the function according to the interval value passed in parameters. This way , if this script is running on all your pages, all pages of the user will update automatically if he logs in / logs out, and not only the page where he fired the login event.

Comment: Brilliant! thanks!  I made some changes to the ajax and now it's working perfectly.  Thank you.  I uncommented out the show hide on success in ajax and now it's looking slick :)

Comment: Describing what the problem is instead of just demonstrating a code sample is a lot more educating also for others in the future with less specific issues, but related to the one described above.

Comment: Also, is it a good idea (or required for that matter) that this script runs every second? What about using `setTimeout` instead for just running it once after a delay? This is just a hack. The real problem is the one I have described in my answer, in regards to caching.

Comment: The comment section is not for extended discussions. Furthermore, my point is that nobody is going to come here from Google and then read the comments. They are not going to know that.

Comment: My answer is not perfect , it's just an idea of how to achieve what the OP was looking for , which was catching the log in from the user in order to display specific content.

Comment: I know that making this script work every 1 seconds is kinda heavy, but the advantage of this solution is that this should update every page on the user log in and not only the page that fired the log in.

Comment: Plus since OP requested a non refresh solution, your changing name script upon refresh is certainly not the solution of the **real problem**.

Comment: My solution doesn't change the script name upon refresh. Are you capable of reading code? It just adds a random parameter to the script file, making the browser **think** it's a new file, even though it's not. That saves the trouble and the bandwidth issues. Fair point though about the automatic sign in, and nice update of your post.

Comment: Yeah you are randomizing the attributes of your scripts in order to fool the browser, but since this change occurs only if you refresh the page i think it has no chance at all to solve OP's problem. Sorry if i wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

This most likely happens due to the browser caching the script within the script tag (and also its global variables).

What you can do is refer to the script externally, and then append some random string behind it that always changes.

```
<script src="myscript.php?randomkey=<?php echo date("U"); ?>">
</script>
```

And the contents of `myscript.php` would then be your code.

This way, the browser will constantly be led to believe that the script has changed. Keep in mind that `myscript.php`'s header mime-type that it broadcasts must be `text/javascript` to make sure it works in all browsers.

I am aware it might not be the most clean solution, but it should work just fine.

Comment: So, put the script as it is inside another file.  I have a helper.js file that the ajax call is in, I guess it could live there.  

Then add the script tag you posted to the header of each file?

Comment: jut realised it can't be within that js file :)

Comment: Nothing displays when I make the changes you suggested. Checked the console and it returns a cannot call to non member object - FFS

Comment: It needs to be in a `PHP` based file, since you are using `PHP` logic such as `echo` inside of it. If it's a `JS` file, it can't interpret the `echo` code. Also, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)